# itex - java - mysql -- reporte pdf sin usar JTable

Tags: java, mysql, itext

soy nuevo en java y estoy intentando hacer un reporte PDF(itext) Individual de cada persona con todos sus atributos en forma de una lista(por asi decir). 
Los datos de la persona las obtengo desde la DB(mysql-- tengo String, int, campo fecha, JComboBox, campo longBlob para la imagen), el reporte en tabla me lo genera bien ... la cosa es que nose como hacer en el formato que necesito, no tengo codigo, la idea es que quede algo asi...

Nombre : nombrePersona                          Foto Perfil : fotoPersona\n
Apellido : apellidoPersona\n
.....
fecha Nacimiento : fechaPersona\n
Genero : generoPersona\n
....(espero se entienda que deberia ir un salto de linea)

```
private void btnReporteFichaActualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      

//        HOJA HORIZONTAL

//        Document documento = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());

//        HOJA VERTICAL

        Document documento = new Document();

    try {
        String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + "/Desktop/Reportes-FuMELJ/Reportes-Personal/Reporte_Personal.pdf"));
        documento.open();

//            PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(3);

//            tabla.addCell("D.N.I.");
//            tabla.addCell("Nombre/s");
//            tabla.addCell("Apellido/s");

        int dato = Integer.parseInt(lblID.getText());

        try {
            ResultSet rs = misDatos.reportePersonal(dato);

//JList para mostrar los datos
            if(rs.next()){

                 List lista = new List();
                 lista.add(new ListItem(rs.getString(3)));//arroja el error descripto abajo

//                    do {                        
//                        tabla.addCell(rs.getString(7));
//                        tabla.addCell(rs.getString(3));
//                        tabla.addCell(rs.getString(4));
//                    } while (rs.next());

//                 documento.add(tabla);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frm_Personal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        documento.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reporte de Personal generado exitosamente.");
    } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
}
```

Ese es el codigo que tengo donde genera PDF con tabla ( esta comentado), eh intentado hacer una lista pero me da error(no situable method found for add(ListItem).....)
espero pueda comprender cual es la idea... 
desde ya gracias!

Comment: La clase List, no la estás poniendo. ¿que tipo de clase es?

Comment: graacias  por responder, mira lo q intente con la lista es crear un lista de tipo List y en ella agregar los item, nose si estoy bien o mal ya soy nuevo en java y quiero hacer un reporte fuera de lo comun(tablas), nose si repondi tu pregunta. Gracias?!

Comment: ya encontre la solucion, desde aki http://java-white-box.blogspot.com/ para el que le interese. Gracias de todas formas!